# C code modification from stm32F to stm32L

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, stm32, stm32ldiscovery

I'm trying to learn and master embedded C, so I was just gonna test a code that I found on Github, which is built for STM32F4 discovery board. The board that I'm actually working on is STM32L152. when I tried to build/run the code (obviously it won't work) the errors I'm getting are mostly related to functions not being defined or "*identifier 'function_name' is undefined*", note that the code file includes a library (lib).
take a look at the code file:
https://github.com/TDAbboud/STM32F4_Examples/tree/master/04_PWM_Servo

Generally speaking, What modifications should be done to successfully run the code on STM32L1?

Thanks

Comment: Way too broad..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two different chips.  Just because they are from ST just because they are ARM based, they are not the same chip.  for starters the stm32f4 is a cortex-m4 the stm32l might not be, 99.9% of your code wont care, just some assembly might.  if the stm32l is a cortex-m0 then you have far fewer instructions so the assembly will matter if it is a cortex-m3 then it wont.

The real isssue is peripherals not that this is two st chips not that this is two arm chips, the peripherals can/will vary.  ST has a number of chips that use the same uart or same gpio or other, but they have more than one uart they use for STM32 chips, and more than one GPIO.  And they mix and match as they make new chips, so if you want to port from one to the other you need to go peripheral by peripheral reading the new and old docs to see what if anything changed.

Sounds like you are using a library so the tool may know from the chip you have chosen what peripherals you have and which library you need, so it might not be finding them because for that chip that peripheral and thus that function and those defines do not apply.  Take it one perpheral at a time and port between chips.

Answer (score 0):

stm32 (L) serise incloud EEPROM which are important when they go to sleep mode and want to recover variables after wakup . so make sure application is running in sleep modes need to save data somewhere. so if you use STM (F) series care needs to attache a external EEPROM